# To compare the Equality and Print the Equal value

Tags: prolog

I want to compare 2 values X and C1 as you can see in code, X is reversed value of C if both values are equal then it should print the compared value please tell me how to do this. It is to print Palindrome Numbers like... 1,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,101....

```
    go(N):-
        write(0),nl,
        go(0,N).
    go(_,0):- !.
    go(A,C):-
        A1 is A,
        C1 is A1 + 1,
       /* write(C1),nl,*/
        rev(C1,X),
       /* write(X),nl,*/

/* To compare the Value of X and C1 and print if compared value is true*/

        NewC is C-1,
        go(C1,NewC).

    rev(Q,E):-

        name(Q, Q1),
        reverse(Q1,E1),
        name(E,E1).
```

Comment: You could do something like `C1 == X -> writeln(X)`.

Comment: when i did this, outout: 0-9 False, and my input was go(15).

Comment: What is the purpose of `A1 is A`? What exactly is `go(N)` supposed to do?

Comment: How about `C1 == X -> writeln(X) ; true.`

Comment: @DanielLyons stil didn't work on my code

Comment: @lurker I am just poor in Prolog programming so may be their must be mistakes. go(N) in N we will put number like e.g 15 and then it will print 15 palindrome numbers starting from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing palindrome numbers is actually a nice task for CLP(FD) and DCGs. First let's describe what the digits of a palindrome number look like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

palindromedigits(Digits) :-        % Digits are palindrome digits if 
   Digits ins 0..9,                % they are between 0 and 9
   Digits = [H|_],                 % and the first digit...
   H #\= 0,                        % ... is different from 0
   phrase(palindrome, Digits).     % and they form a palindrome

palindrome -->                     % a palindrome is
   [].                             % an empty list
palindrome -->                     % or
   [_].                            % a list with a single element
palindrome -->                     % or
   [A],                            % an element A
   palindrome,                     % followed by a palindrome
   [A].                            % followed by an element A
```

To test if a number is a palindrome, you could turn it into a list of digits and `palindromedigits/1` has to hold for that list. To generate such numbers, you could use `length/2` to describe lists of all possible lengths, `palindromedigits/1` again has to hold for those lists and the digits have to be multiplied by their respective powers of ten and summed up. Since leading zeros are excluded by `palindromedigits/1`, you'd have to add a fact for `0`, if you want to include it in the palindrome numbers. That might look something like this:

```
palindromenumber(0).                % 0 is a palindromenumber
palindromenumber(PN) :-             % rule for testing numbers
   number(PN),                      % succeeds if PN is a number 
   number_codes(PN,C),              % C is a list of codes corresponding to the digits
   maplist(plus(48),Digits,C),      % codes and digits are off by 48
   palindromedigits(Digits).        % Digits is a palindrome   
palindromenumber(PN) :-             % rule for generating numbers
   var(PN),                         % succeeds if PN is a variable
   length(Digits,_),                % Digits is a list of length 0,1,2,...
   palindromedigits(Digits),        % Digits is a palindrome
   digits_number_(Digits,PN,1,0),   % Digits correspond to the number PN
   label(Digits).                   % labels the list Digits with actual numbers
```

Note that the codes corresponding to the digits are off by 48, hence the goal with `maplist/3`, e.g.:

```
?- number_codes(123,C), maplist(plus(48),Digits,C).
C = [49, 50, 51],                                    % <- the codes
Digits = [1, 2, 3].                                  % <- the actual digits
```

The predicate `digits_number_/4` is fairly straight forward. It is called with `1` as the initial power of ten and `0` as the initial accumulator for the number. The digits are multiplied with the power of ten corresponding to their position in the number and subsequently added to the accumulator. If the list of digits is empty, the accumulator holds the number corresponding to the list of digits.

```
digits_number_([],PN,_,PN).         
digits_number_([D|Ds],PN,P,Acc) :-  
   Acc1 #= Acc + D*B,               
   P10 #= P*10,                     
   digits_number_(Ds,PN,P10,Acc1).
```

Note that it doesn't matter that the digits are multiplied with the powers in reverse order, because it's a palindrome number.

Now you can query for palindrome numbers:

```
?- palindromenumber(PN).
PN = 0 ;
PN = 1 ;
PN = 2 ;
.
.
.
PN = 33 ;
PN = 44 ;
PN = 55 ;
.
.
.
PN = 666 ;
PN = 676 ;
PN = 686 ;
.
.
.
PN = 7667 ;
PN = 7777 ;
PN = 7887 
.
.
.
```

Or you can test if a number is a palindrome:

```
?- palindromenumber(121).
true ;
false.

?- palindromenumber(123).
false.

?- palindromenumber(12321).
true ;
false.
```

**EDIT**

To address the question in your comment, you can do that by describing a relation between such a sequence and it's length. So you'll have a predicate with arity two instead of arity one. Let's give it a nice descriptive name, say `firstN_palindromicnumbers/2`. The actual realation is described by a predicate with an additional argument that holds the current candidate to be examined. Since you want to start the sequence with 1, that will be the argument firstN_palindromicnumbers_/3 will be called with:

```
firstN_palindromicnumbers(N,PNs) :-
   firstN_palindromicnumbers_(N,PNs,1).       % sequence starts with 1
```

The argument that holds the candidates will be increased by 1 through the recursions, while the first argument, `N`, will be decreased every time a candidate turns out to be an actual palindromic number. So the predicate eventually ends up with `N` being `0`, an empty list and a candidate we don't care for. That will be the base case. Otherwise the head of the list is the smallest palindromic number in the (remainder of the) sequence. You can reuse the goals `number_codes/2` and `maplist/3` from above to describe a list of digits corresponding to the current candidate and the DCG `palindrome//0` to state that the digits have to be a palindrome. The other goals from the predicate `palindromedigits/1` won't be needed, since the candidates will be 1,2,3,..., thus consisting of (at least one) digit(s) from 0 to 9 without leading zeros. You can express this in Prolog like so:

```
firstN_palindromicnumbers_(0,[],_C).          % base case
firstN_palindromicnumbers_(N1,[C0|PNs],C0) :- % case: C0 is a palindrome
   N1 #> 0,                                   % sequence is not of desired length yet
   number_codes(C0,Codes),
   maplist(plus(48),Digits,Codes),
   phrase(palindrome, Digits),                % digits form a palindrome
   N0 #= N1-1,                                % sequence of length N1-1 has to be described yet
   C1 #= C0+1,                                % C1 is the next candidate
   firstN_palindromicnumbers_(N0,PNs,C1).     % PNs is the rest of the sequence
firstN_palindromicnumbers_(N1,PNs,C0) :-      % case: C0 ain't a palindrome
   N1 #> 0,                                   % sequence is not of desired length yet
   number_codes(C0,Codes),
   maplist(plus(48),Digits,Codes),
   \+ phrase(palindrome, Digits),             % digits don't form a palindrome
   C1 #= C0+1,                                % C1 is the next candidate 
   firstN_palindromicnumbers_(N1,PNs,C1).     % PNs is the rest of the sequence
```

Now you can query the predicate for a sequence of palindromic numbers of given length (Note that with SWI-Prolog you might have to hit **w** to see the entire list):

```
?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(15,PNs).
PNs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...] [write]               % <- hit the w key
PNs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66] ;
false.

?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(25,PNs).
PNs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161] ;
false.
```

You can also use the predicate to check if a given list is the sequence of the first `N` palindrommic numbers:

```
?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(N,[1,2,3,4,5]).
N = 5 ;
false.

?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(N,[0|_]).
false.

?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(N,[1,2,3,4,11]).
false.
```

And the most general query yields the expected answers as well:

```
?- firstN_palindromicnumbers(N,PNs).
N = 0,
PNs = [] ;
N = 1,
PNs = [1] ;
N = 2,
PNs = [1, 2] ;
N = 3,
PNs = [1, 2, 3] ;
.
.
.
```

Comment: How can we make it that if i put palindromenumber(100) then it print 100 palindrome numbers starting from 1

Comment: @ZainAli: I updated my answer to address that question.